# How to generate triangle data for dynamic 3D meshes

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, mesh

I'm developing a game in which I want to be able to modify 3D meshes, but I'm having issues with generating the triangle data for the meshes. I tried to work out the math by myself, but I've only managed to get a partially working system, so does anyone know of any algorithms or methods that I could use to do this? Any information on the subject would be appreciated, as I've never attempted anything like this before. I'm using the Unity Engine. I wasn't sure whether to post this here or in the math section, but I'll try here first.

Comment: For part of my game I need 3D objects that change shape, there could potentially be 100's of different objects that change shape. The shapes could be quite complex, with a lot of triangles. I need to be able to be able to dynamically "remove" parts of an object and create holes in objects.

Answer (score 0):

I edited one of these classes to help draw a custom shape from triangles. Maybe it will help you get started:

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ProceduralPrimitives